# How to use place inside a frame embedded in a canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, scrollbar

I am using labels to display data. However I have so many labels positioned below each other that I cant fit them all on the same window. I wish to use a scroll bar to scroll through the labels. However as I have read this is not so simple. As I understand, my best bet is to use a frame to gather all of my labels, and then insert the frame into a canvas, that can then be used in parallel with the scrollbar, although I am having trouble doing so. 
The function that I am using to create my labels is

```
def Tab(root, y):
    #Print the team
    playerTeam = Label(root, bg = "white", text = "Hello")
    playerTeam.config(height = 1, width = 13)
    playerTeam.place(x=20,y=y)
```

I have attempted to add the following code in conjunction with my function

```
def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
frame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=frame, anchor="nw")

frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

Tab(frame, 20)
```

When ran, a blank window is produced. 
However, when .grid is used instead of .place, in Tab() It works correctly, and the label is shown on the window. Although, when I call Tab() multiple times, the labels go off of the window and the ability to scroll down is not available.

How can I get the .place function to work correctly.
And secondly how can I get the scroll bar to work correctly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `place` doesn't work like the other geometry managers -- it won't change the size of its parent. Thus, even though you put a large(ish) label in the frame, the frame remains its default size of one pixel wide and one pixel tall. It's there, you just can't see it.

You can verify this by giving the frame an explicit width and height (and adding a distinctive color helps visualize it, too):

```
frame.configure(width=100, height=100, background="bisque")
```

From the [official documentation for place](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/place.htm#M21):

> Unlike many other geometry managers (such as the packer) the placer
>   does not make any attempt to manipulate the geometry of the master
>   windows or the parents of slave windows (i.e. it does not set their
>   requested sizes). To control the sizes of these windows, make them
>   windows like frames and canvases that provide configuration options
>   for this purpose.

I strongly encourage you to *not* use `place`. Tkinter's `pack` and `grid` geometry managers are exceptionally good at laying out widgets. If you use `place`, you have to do a lot of math yourself, and the result likely won't resize properly or withstand changes in resolution or font size without a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, but I really cant see the grid and pack geometry managers working well with my interface design. But in addition, why will the scroll bar not work in the example that i gave?

Comment: The scrollbars don't work because the `scrollregion` isn't set, because the frame is tiny. Set the `scrollregion` to a value larger than the canvas and the scrollbars will work. I'd be willing to bet there is almost no interface design you can come up with that can't work with `pack` or `grid`, except for a design that calls for the user to be able to interactively move widgets around.

Comment: Ok thanks. I would be able to use the pack/grid methods however at the moment ive found it hard to get the labels where i want them without the labels becoming set too closely together.

Comment: both `grid` and `pack` have options to add padding on all sides of a widget.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Does a solution for this exist?

Comment: @A.Shenzy: yes, a solution exists. Click the "Ask Question" button if you need help with a specific problem.